# Unicode (U+2212) error pops up out of nowhere

Tags: unicode

Since I've been using an acronym in one paragraph, the unicode error pops out of nowhere.
It is particularly weird, since it appears and disappears from itself when I'm changing something in the text.

The block of text looks like this:

> According to the cyber lexicon of the \ac{FSB} cyber risks are "the
> combination of cyber incidents occurring and their impact"
> \cite[p.9]{FSB1}. The International Association of Insurance
> Supervisors defines cyber risk more comprehensively as "any risks that
> emanate from the use of electronic data and its transmission,
> including technology tools such as the internet and telecommunications
> networks. It also encompasses physical damage that can be caused by
> cybersecurity incidents, fraud committed by misuse of data, any
> liability arising from data storage, and the availability, integrity,
> and confidentiality of electronic information − be it related to
> individuals, groups, or governments".

I haven't changed anything else in the documentsettings etc. - yet the error appears only for this paragraph so I am presuming it has to do something with the acronym (/ac) since I've only started using acronyms from here.

Comment: Somehow `−` (U+2212) slipped in between “information” and ”be”. It's wrong input for an en-dash `--`. Fix also the undirected quotes.

Comment: No it does not come from nowhere, you have a U+2212  −  (minus sign) in your source

Comment: Thank you. I totally misunderstood that error.